# Serving out user customized scripts in high volume

Tags: javascript, python, apache, postgresql, flask

We currently have a script which is served out via a web server (Flask through Apache WSGI).

This is a user customizable Javascript file which includes some common logic, and some user customizable parameters which differ from user-to-user.

The current method to serve it out seems very inefficient to me, and that's to store each users' config in a local database and append on the common logic code before sending it out. For example:

```
var user_config = {...};
// ====== separation ======
var logic = (function() {
    // Consume config data here
});
```

The config is done with users logging into our website and customizing a number of features they want, but the config is basically a very large JSON.

The reason this was done originally was to make the client code as simple as possible. They'd simply include a script tag on their website with their ID:

```
<script src="http://path.to.script?id=ABC></script>
```

The problem I'm finding now is, I'm trying to modify the originally developed method to better handle a high-load, as it seems to be struggling at the moment.

What would be the way to serve out these per-user customized scripts to best reduce load on our server(s), while maybe taking advantage of some caching or other load reducing features.

Comment: "high load", what part of your software stack is causing this high load? Is it Apache, Python (Flask), PostgreSQL or something else?

Comment: I'll have a look into profiling soon, but we just noticed that many clients were getting timeouts when trying to retrieve the script on their page. At the moment I suspect it is the database query though.

Comment: What is the Apache MPM being used? What is the Apache MPM settings used? What version of mod_wsgi is being used? Are you using mod_wsgi daemon mode? If daemon mode, how is the daemon process group configured? It is very easy to screw up the Apache configuration, or at least end up with a sub optimal configuration if you never attempted to change the defaults to align with your requirements. Apache is usually set up for PHP which goes poorly when using Python. Besides Apache, could also be the database.

Comment: "_At the moment I suspect it is the database query_" - I would confirm where the problem is before you try and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what is customised & how. If possible, have users serialise / json encode their config parameters in the script query params.

#### Edit

Now that I have a little more info on the situation, I think you're not far off an optimal setup.

Since the config is quite large when serialized / converted to JSON, then I think yes - you're going to have to keep this on a DB. Maybe make a table / DB dedicated to this. UserId field + Config JSON.

The best way IMO to mitigate the high load on the server would be to implement a RAM based caching layer like memcached.

Obvi make sure your db is optimized too, index the ID field if it's not already indexed.

Then put all of this behind something like Varnish.

If your high load is caused by the sheer number of different requests that could spike at any given time, then I think you need to do some work to keep the cache warm constantly for all your active users.

If your scripts require a DB write for recording metrics, then perhaps consider moving that functionality into the client side script and have it do an AJAX call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated the question with more details, but there are many many settings they can customize by logging into their user-page in our company website.